# Why some area in the ocean seems to have like "wind barrier"?

Tags: meteorology

When looking at the earth wind map, some lines clearly distinguish themselve and act as "frontier" between stream of wind. I was wondering what it was and what was causing them? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you have to explain what a "frontier" is

Comment: in the photo, it's the line that separate wind flows in two distinguishable area. Sorry I am aware the term is poorly chosen, I was hoping the photo would help understand. Please let me know if you still can't see what I mean.

Comment: It definitely looks like a visualization artifact. Are you showing wind at constant pressure? wind at constant height? If the color relates to "absolute wind velocity from left to right" then what you are showing is "absolute wind velocity from left to right" almost 0 in certain region because the streamlines are turning from going to the right to going to the left ... therefore their component left to right goes to zero.

Comment: @EarlGrey: it is not an artefact or an artwork (though i can imagine somebody might hang it up on the wall :-)). The visualization just emphesizes the features. Look at the current situation over the northern Atlantic. Two high pressure areas, a mall stomy low just south of the eastern it, a weak cold front in the east. For a full synopsis we need some more data.  Here's a chart that fits the image: https://ocean.weather.gov/Atl_tab.php Until expired ofc, be quick, it's weather :-)

Comment: the picture you have posted is from https://earth.nullschool.net and is a map of the wind,the thin area is of windshear where the wind changes direction.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr7mK.png was I 'quick"?

Comment: Thanks @uhoh :-)